# Proper way to set up rsnapshot over ssh on multiple machines

Tags: ssh, rsnapshot

I am using the answer in this post to part of my question:

[Proper way to set up rsnapshot over ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325100/proper-way-to-set-up-rsnapshot-over-ssh)

However, this post is seven years old and also I have an additional question.

I have the same scenario, except that I have a server B and a server C that need to use rsnapshot over ssh to back up to server A.

Question: how can I set the rsnapshot configuration file to not confuse the two (server B and server C) in terms of storage, schedule (via cron), and so on?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Do you want to backup two servers B and C to the single destination A? If so, just create two configurations and refer to them explicitly with `rsnapshot -c {config}`

Comment: That's what I'm asking, and that's the answer I think. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to backup two servers B and C to the single destination A? If so, just create two configurations and refer to them explicitly with `rsnapshot -c {config} ...`